# ubuntu & win8 help!

Tags: installation

I want to install the ubuntu 12.04.2 in my computer, which already has windows 8.
I have no idea how to do it, I cannot understand a single word of the other post since I'm new in all this.
Can somebody help me using easy lenguage (and pictures if possible), please?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need a iso Ubuntu disk. With some new Window 8 computers you have to  enter the Bios right at start up and disable the save boot option. To enter the Bios are not the same on all the different computers. Some you have to press Del or F10 etc. Normally right at start up at the bottom of the screen for 1 or 2 seconds it will give you the info. Then change the boot order to CD first then second USB then thirtly HDD and also disable the - **save boot option** - if available. Insert the Ubuntu CD reboot and follow the instructions. On some of these new machines if you install to dual boot, it will start to install but stop and on some machines even open your CD drive. Then you have a chance to install deleting Windows and use the whole HDD for Ubuntu only. If This still do not work use a 8GB USB stick and install Ubuntu on it. Boot from it and format the HDD. Now you should be able to install Ubuntu from the iso CD. If you do not want to do any of the installation run your Computer From the biggest USB stick you can afford. The USB stick is not as fast as a HDD but you can save your files on the Windows HDD.